# Boost Console logger writing all messages to STDERR after sinks are setup

Tags: c++, windows, logging, boost

I am using the C++ Boost Log library (1.54) to do logging for my Windows application. I have defined a simple class to setup the logging macros & take a Boost config file that defines the sinks for my application.

LoggerClass.h

```
class LoggerClass {
  public:
    static void Initialization(const std::string& configurationFile)
}

BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT(my_logger, boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log_trivial::severity_level>);

#define LOG_INFO_MESSAGE BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::severity_level::info)
```

LoggerClass.cpp

```
void LoggerClass::Initialization(const std::string& configurationFile)
{
    boost::log::register_simple_formatter_factory< boost::log::trivial::severity_level, char >("Severity");
    boost::log::register_simple_filter_factory< boost::log::trivial::severity_level, char >("Severity");

    boost::log::register_simple_formatter_factory< unsigned int, char >("Line");
    boost::log::register_simple_filter_factory< unsigned int, char >("Line");

    boost::log::register_formatter_factory("TimeStamp", boost::make_shared< time_formatter_factory >());

    std::ifstream file(configurationFile);
    boost::log::init_from_stream(file);

    boost::log::add_common_attributes();

    my_boost::get();
}
```

My config file:

```
[Core]
DisableLogging=false

[Sinks.Sink1]

Destination=Console

Asynchronous=false

AutoFlush=true
```

If I call these macros before setting up any sinks, the default sink writes the first message to STDOUT, as it should.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[] {
  LOG_INFO_MESSAGE << "Before Initialization()"; //writes to STDOUT

  LoggerClass::Initialization("log.conf"); //sets up the console sink

  LOG_INFO_MESSAGE << "After Initialization()"; //writes to STDERR???
}
```

However, once I have defined a Console sink in my config file & called boost::log::init_from_stream() method, all messages end up in STDERR, not STDOUT as I would expect.

```
C:\Test\TestLogger.exe > std.txt 2> err.txt
```

std.txt

```
[2014-05-08 12:57:17.293972] [0x00004b58] [info]    Before Initialization()
```

err.txt

```
After Initialization()
```

**Why don't messages go to STDOUT by default after the Console sink is setup?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Boost source header file (Boost\log\utility\setup\console.hpp), the Console logger writes to std::clog, which is associated with the C stream STDERR.